# Android - Close all activities (FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP/clearTaskOnLaunch didn't help)

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have "MainMenuActivity" in my application, from which I want to log out. After pressing the back button, this activity should start "Logout activity", which does some logout stuff and then finishes the application.

Method called onBackPressed() from MainMenuActivity:

```
    public static void logoutAction(final AbstractActivity activity) {
        Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_btn_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(activity, iess.student.login.LogoutActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            activity.startActivity(i);
            activity.finish();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

Then, "LogoutActivity" executes AsyncTask, which at the end of its work calls `finish()` on LogoutActivity.

My problem is, that if other activities were launched before MainMenuActivity, i.e. A -> B -> MainMenuActivity, then after pressing back button Logout activity does its work, finishes, but instead of closing the application, activity B comes to front. I tried to launch MainMenuActivity from activity B with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and then call `finish()` on B, but in that case A came to front. I also tried to set:

```
<activity android:name="abc.def.LogoutActivity" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"></activity>
```

But the result was the same as before. Could you please help me what should I do?

---

OK, so I finally managed it. After creating an activity, I register it in `static ArrayList<Activity>`. After "LogoutActivity" does its work; it just calls `finish()` on each Activity registered in ArrayList. It works, but I guess it's not really nice. But I haven't figured out how to do this with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.

Comment: Do you have an activity with launchMode?

Comment: seems, from API 11 you can use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

Answer (score 0):

As @sandrstar says in the comment:

> from API 11 you can use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`

It works very well for me, as it removes all Activities, not just the ones on top.